# struts+ajax not execute all methods in the action and ajax execute success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

The condition is so weird that i don't know what i should to do and where i need to debug. Maybe the reason that result in this condition is not in the struts or ajax,but i can't find where i am wrong. I want to know if anyone encounter the same thing.Any help will thanks.

I use jquery+ajax to send data to action in struts,but it does not execute all steps in the action and ajax execute success function.

here is my .js code

```
  var jsonString=JSON.stringify(datas);
    jsonString=encodeURI(jsonString);
    jsonString=encodeURI(jsonString);
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"headSalerScheduleSubmit.action? branch="+branch+"&week="+week+"&json="+jsonString,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        success:function(){
            alert("make an plan!");
        }
    });
```

here is my struts code.

```
public String execute(){        
    String branch=request.getParameter("branch");
    String week=request.getParameter("week");
    String json=request.getParameter("json");
    json = URLDecoder.decode(json, "UTF-8"); 
    System.out.println("json is "+json);
    JSONArray jsonarray=JSONArray.fromObject(json);
    System.out.println("jsonarray size is "+jsonarray.size());
    //save Schedule


int scheduleid=scheduleDao.getNum();
    System.out.println("scheduleid is "+scheduleid);
    int branchid=branchDao.searchBranchByName(branch).get(0).getBranchid();
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    int weekNum=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1-weekNum);
    int day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    Date date=new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    Schedule schedule=new Schedule();
    schedule.setScheduleid(scheduleid);
    schedule.setWeek(week);
    schedule.setBranchid(branchid);
    schedule.setDate(date);
    scheduleDao.save(schedule);
    return "success";
}
```

when ajax send data,function execute to this step just stop `int scheduleid=scheduleDao.getNum();`

Why?

Comment: No clue. What's in the logs? Does `scheduleDao` have a non-`null` value? Is `getNum()` failing? Not enough information to help beyond that.

Comment: Is it only the question you want to as whY?

Comment: @DaveNewton The answer could be inferred from the comment if someone will answer yes three times.